# home screen widget text view not updating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, broadcastreceiver

This is the code of my program -

```
package com.nadeem.todos;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class todo_widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private TodoSQLiteHelper dbHelper;
String[] widget_title = { "", "", "", "", "", "" };
String[] widget_content = { "", "", "", "", "", "" };
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH = "ActionReceiverRefresh";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_OPEN = "ActionReceiverOpen";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.contentw2, pendingIntent);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.contentw3, pendingIntent);
    Intent i1 = new Intent(context, todo_widget.class);
    i1.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.flip, pi);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.contentw1, pi);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
            .getInstance(context);

    int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(
            new ComponentName(context, todo_widget.class));
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH)) {
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.titlew1, widget_title[3]);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.contentw1, widget_content[3]);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(ids, views);

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
            AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE)) {
        dbHelper = new TodoSQLiteHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] tableColumns = new String[] { "_id", "title", "todo" };

        int j = 0;

        Cursor cursor = db.query("todos", tableColumns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            if (j < 6) {
                widget_title[j] = cursor.getString(1);
                widget_content[j] = cursor.getString(2);
            }
            j++;

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        final int N = ids.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = ids[i];
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.titlew1, widget_title[0]);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.titlew2, widget_title[1]);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.titlew3, widget_title[2]);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.contentw1, widget_content[0]);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.contentw2, widget_content[1]);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.contentw3, widget_content[2]);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

        }
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
    }
```

My problem is that the text view in onRecieve method does not get updated when the Action_widget_refresh is true. I have set a pending intent on a text view so that when it is clicked the text of the text view (R.id.content1) changes. But when i click on the text view the text view dissappears. i have no idea why this is happening. Other than that the code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call [`appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget%28int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29), the RemoveViews you pass in needs to "contain a complete representation of the widget".  That means you need to set the text for your TextViews every time, not just when the text should change.  By only setting the text that changes, you're losing the text that you want to remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be doing:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH)) {
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.titlew1, widget_title[3]);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.contentw1, widget_content[3]);
    final int N = ids.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = ids[i];
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```